# Splitting a comma separated string

Tags: azure, terraform

I have an output that is a multi-valued, comma separated string.

#### input.tf

```
resource "azurerm_app_service" "testap" {
  name                = "MySuperCoolAppServer001"
  location            = "eastus"
  resource_group_name = "notshown"
  app_service_plan_id = "notshown"
}
```

#### output.tf

```
output "output_tf_testap_outbound_ip_addresses" {
  value = "${azurerm_app_service.testap.outbound_ip_addresses}"
}
```

And I get this in the console:

> output_tf_testap_outbound_ip_addresses =
>   1.2.3.4,1.2.3.5,1.2.3.6,1.2.3.7,1.2.3.8,1.2.3.9

How do I get the first item of the list?  In this case, I'm trying to isolate the value:

> 1.2.3.4

Is there a way to get a "collection" of all the items when the total number of items is not known before run time? (The list above has 6 items).

The following code doesn't seem to work:

```
output "first_ip" {
  value = ["${azurerm_app_service.testap.outbound_ip_addresses[0]}"]
}
```

===================== APPEND =================

first_ip_no_index works.  first_ip does not

```
output "first_ip_no_index" {
  value = ["${split(",", azurerm_app_service.tf_middle_tier_azurerm_app_service.outbound_ip_addresses)}"]
}

output "first_ip" {
  value = "${split(",", azurerm_app_service.tf_middle_tier_azurerm_app_service.outbound_ip_addresses)[0]}"
}
```

first_ip  generated this error:

> Error reading config for output first_ip: parse error at 1:91:
>   expected "}" but found "["

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`split()` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#split-delim-string-) to split a string into a list.

```
output "output_tf_testap_outbound_ip_addresses" {
  value = ["${split(",", azurerm_app_service.testap.outbound_ip_addresses)}"]
}
```

After that you can then index it by using the [`element(list, index)` syntax](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#element-list-index-):

```
output "first_ip" {
  value = "${element(split(",", azurerm_app_service.testap.outbound_ip_addresses), 0}"
}
```

You should also normally be able to use the [`list\[index\]` syntax](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#user-list-variables) like this:

```
output "first_ip" {
  value = "${split(",", azurerm_app_service.testap.outbound_ip_addresses)[0]}"
}
```

However there seems to be a bug in Terraform 0.11 that prevents slicing the result of the `split` function, throwing the following error:

> Error: Error loading /tmp/tf-split-test/main.tf: Error reading config
>   for output foo: parse error at 1:25: expected "}" but found "["

You could use a [`local`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html) to split the list and then slice that to get around this if you'd prefer to use this syntax over the `element` function.

```
locals {
  outbound_ip_addresses_list = "${split(",", azurerm_app_service.testap.outbound_ip_addresses)}"
}

output "first_ip" {
  value = "${local.outbound_ip_addresses_list[0]}"
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the split to work..but not the indexer (0).            This works:  output "first_ip" {
  value = ["${split(",", azurerm_app_service.tf_middle_tier_azurerm_app_service.outbound_ip_addresses)}"]
}    but not first_ip as listed above.  #soClose

Comment: "Error reading config for output first_ip: parse error at 1:91: expected "}" but found "[""

Comment: Ack, looks like a bug in the HCL parser there. I'm tempted to raise an issue for it but Terraform 0.12 is moving to HCL2 which will change a lot of things and might fix this. In general though I'd have expected the `outbound_ip_addresses` from `azurerm_app_service` to be a list type anyway which would make this a lot simpler.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks for following up.

Comment: Here's a link.  My only (rhetorical) question is why is it called 0.12? (as opposed to 0.11)?  Seems like a huge change.  Maybe 0.20?     Anyways.........  https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/terraform-0-1-2-preview

Comment: Latest release is 0.11 and this is a large and potentially breaking change so by semver this should be a major release which means incrementing the first significant figure. So pre 1.0 a breaking change pushes from 0.11 to 0.12. But this is getting pretty off topic here. I've updated my answer with fixed versions for 0.11 anyway (use element or slice a local).